# Using member in swi prolog

Tags: prolog

I am totaly new to prolog and have just started. I am currently learning about the build in function 'member' that seems simple; however, it returns the opposite of what I would expect it to do.

I tried printing the output of a very simple query:

```
member(6, [2,4,3,5]).
```

My expectation was that the output of this would be **False**

However, it returns **True**

I played with this further trying:

```
member(2, [2,4,3,5]).
```

Which returns **False**!?

Could someone explain if this is a mistake by me or that this is normal for prolog to do?

Comment: Looks like a mistake by you.

Comment: Why should `?- member(6, [2,4,3,5]).` be true?